# sql select from multiple line

Tags: sql

I have this table in my phpMyAdmin ( named TagFilm )

```
id   tagId    filmId
1    1        141
2    5        141
3    4        141
4    3        132
5    1        121
```

And I need to say : take me all the filmId where tagid = 1 Or 5 And where the filmId have tagId= 4 necessarily

I try this but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT   *  FROM     tagFilm
WHERE    tagid IN (1,5) AND tagId = 4
GROUP BY FilmId
```

Comment: your where clause is impossible. `in(1,5) AND tagId=4` requires that tagid have TWO different values simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is to `select` filmid's which have a tag either `1 or 5` and also a tagid of `4`. In other database engines, which support `intersect` this is easier. As Mysql doesn't support `intersect` you should use multiple `self-joins` to get the result.

```
select distinct t1.filmid
from tagfilm t1
join tagfilm t2 on t1.filmid = t2.filmid and t2.tagid in (1, 5) 
join tagfilm t3 on t2.filmid = t3.filmid and t3.tagid = 4
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a214/1) with sample data

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so here is my reply. For starters, you have no entries with a `filmId` of 4. Be wary of case-sensitive searches, as you switch between upper and lower case characters. In your original query you're searching for `tagId` twice as well. You say it doesn't work, are you not getting results or does your query error out? Guessing it's the second.

`SELECT * FROM TagFilm
WHERE tagId IN (1,5) AND filmId = 4
GROUP BY filmId`

Comment: Sorry, i've just edit, I would say => take me all the filmId where tagid = 1 Or 5 And where tagId= 4 necessarily

Comment: tagId = 1 or 5 and tagId = 4 will never work. The second condition says it must equal 4, but the first says it must be 1 or 5.

Comment: I want the request take all the tagId 1 and all the tagid5 but just if the movie concerned have a tagid 4 ( I hope I was clear...sorry for my bad english )

Comment: So which `id` do you want based on your example? I'm thinking you want 1 and 2 but not 5.

Comment: In my example, I want filmId 141